# var connect = require('connect'); var app = connect(), What is connect()? is it a method or a constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im fairly new to Nodejs and connect, I was looking through some tutorials and examples and come across .
What is the purpose of connect() and is it a method or a constructor?

```
  var connect = require('connect'); 
    var app = connect(),
```

Comment: It's a function that when called returns a new object.

Answer (score 1):

> Connect is an extensible HTTP server framework for node, providing
>   high performance "plugins" known as middleware.
>    according to [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) this site

for more info about **connect** and **middleware** please refer this like [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect#getting-started)

Comment: Question is not about what **connect** module is. Question is about what `connect()` do (in the 2nd line)

Answer (score 0):

When you require a module, it returns it's exports property. In the connect module they set the module.exports to be a function, that creates an app. In modules that returns an object with multiple functions (like fs), you can call its functions ( like fs.open() ), but this time you get a function, so you can just call connect(), and it returns a new instance of an app.